# Support armv6 and armv7 in the same ipa

Tags: xcode, ios, armv7, armv6

I have an XCode project configured like this:

- Project Format: XCode 3.1-compatible
- Architectures : Standard (armv6 armv7)
- Base SDK      : Latest iOS (currently set to iOS 4.2)
- Build Active Architecture Only : UNCHECKED
- Valid Architecures: armv6 armv7

My question: Does the resulting binary (.ipa) have 2 executables in it - one for each architecture, or just some different object files for each architecture or is the split even finer grained than that?

Just curious.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what you described, the ipa should have a multi-architecture binary with both arm6 and arm7.  You can check it with the `file` command in terminal.  Inside of your app bundle is a executable that will have the same name as the app, **myApp.app/myApp**. Entering:

```
file myApp.app/myApp
```

in terminal will then print what it contains for you to double check.  It should list the 2 architectures.

Answer (score 5):

It will produce two binaries and then stick them together in a so-called "fat binary". You can play around with sticking multiple architectures in the same executable yourself using the `lipo` command.

To clarify: You will have two executables inside a single file. This is logically a single executable (both are your app), but one version targets one architecture and the other version targets the other architecture.

Comment: There must be some overlap or re-use, because a single arch binary is 2.2MB, and a double arch binary is 2.7MB, not a trivial difference, but also not double.