# How to know if your .ipa is 64-Bit

Tags: ios, ios8, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I've built an .ipa file with following flags armv7 armv7s and arm64.
Is there any way/ tool through which i can make sure the .ipa does have the 64-Bit support?

How does apple find out during app submission if the app binary does have 64-Bit support.

Comment: Standard Architectures includes both. If you look at the list in includes armv7 (32-bit) and arm64 (64-bit). armv7s was quietly dropped because there is only one device that gets a slight gain from it (iPad 4). _Reading:_ [Converting YourApp to 64 Bits](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering carlodurso

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the options is to use `lipo -info %path-to-executable%` make sure you are not using path to .app folder or .ipa archive.

Comment: Just to elaborate, to extract exe from the .ipa check out the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737259/support-armv6-and-armv7-in-the-same-ipa

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script that takes `.ipa` file as an input and returns what architecture the app supports -
(replace  and  with yours)

```
ORIGINAL_FILE="<file path>"
FILE_NAME=$(basename $ORIGINAL_FILE)
EXPANDED_DIR="/Users/<username>/Downloads/expanded_app/$FILE_NAME"
PLIST_FILE="$APP_DIR/Info.plist"
APP_DIR="$EXPANDED_DIR/Payload/*.app"
unzip -q "$ORIGINAL_FILE" -d "$EXPANDED_DIR"

executable_file_name=$(/user/rover/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleExecutable" $PLIST_FILE)
EXECUTABLE_FILE="$APP_DIR/$executable_file_name"
app_architecture_list=$(lipo -info $EXECUTABLE_FILE)
echo $app_architecture_list
```

Now, this `app_architecture_list` will give you result that will contain `armv6` or `armv7` or `arm64`, by which you can figure out.

*Note* - you will need `PlistBuddy` for this.