# Codename One - iOS debug build install fails

Tags: ios, codenameone

With "Send iOS Debug build" command I successfully obtained the debug version of my app.

I used a 64-bit iPad mini 2 (you can verify [here](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51adfbd9e4b095d664d9b869/t/5a577ff4e4966b1f7d784921/1515683829075/Matrix+16by9-8k.pdf) it has a 64-bit architecture) [**INCORRECT, READ UPDATE 3**] as test device, so I didn't add the ios.debug.archs build hint.

For installing the app, I sent the OTA link through email, but the process produced the error "Unable to Download App... could not be installed at this time.".

I followed the iOS Signing Wizard (http://www.codenameone.com/manual/signing.html) to generate certificates and I verified all described here (https://www.codenameone.com/blog/my-ios-build-wont-install.html).

What can I do?

---

**UPDATE**

These are logs from the iPad:

installd[987] : 0x3c3000 -[MIInstallableBundle performVerificationWithError:]: 487: Incorrect architecture at file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.vRoN6W/extracted/Payload/MyApplication.app/MyApplication

installd[987] : 0x3c3000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed

itunesstored[916] : 0x1ca5000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=15 "Incorrect architecture at file:///private/var/mobile/Library

---

**UPDATE 2**

This is the codenameone_settings.properties file:

```
codename1.arg.java.version=8
codename1.ios.appid=F35988TNH4.it.sitespa.ios.socialapp
codename1.ios.release.provision=C\:\\Users\\[...]\\SocialAppForIOS_distribution.mobileprovision
codename1.arg.rim.obfuscation=false
codename1.arg.ios.newStorageLocation=true
codename1.arg.ios.objC=true
codename1.j2me.nativeTheme=nbproject/nativej2me.res
codename1.arg.ios.project_type=ios
codename1.arg.ios.interface_orientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait\:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
codename1.displayName=SocialAppForIOS
codename1.arg.ios.pods.platform=,7.0
codename1.android.keystoreAlias=
codename1.ios.release.certificate=C\:\\Users\\[...]\\SocialAppForIOS_distribution.p12
codename1.android.keystorePassword=
codename1.ios.provision=
codename1.arg.android.release=true
codename1.arg.ios.dsym=false
codename1.arg.ios.glAppDelegateHeader=\n\#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"
codename1.arg.ios.statusbar_hidden=false
codename1.arg.ios.afterFinishLaunching=[GMSServices provideAPIKey\:@"[...]"];
codename1.languageLevel=5
codename1.android.keystore=
codename1.arg.ios.pods=,GoogleMaps
codename1.vendor=CodenameOne
codename1.arg.javascript.googlemaps.key=[...]
codename1.arg.win.ver=8
codename1.arg.ios.locationUsageDescription=Some functionality of the application depends on your location
codename1.arg.android.playService.maps=true
codename1.ios.certificatePassword=
codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword=password
codename1.arg.android.GoogleMaps.minPlayServicesVersion=9.4.0
codename1.mainName=MyApplication
codename1.arg.ios.pods.sources=,https\://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
codename1.ios.release.certificatePassword=password
codename1.arg.ios.prerendered_icon=false
codename1.ios.debug.certificate=C\:\\Users\\[...]\\SocialAppForIOS_development.p12
libVersion=202
codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> <uses-permission android\:name\="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/><uses-feature         android\:glEsVersion\="0x00020000"         android\:required\="true"/>
codename1.arg.ios.application_exits=false
codename1.description=
codename1.secondaryTitle=CodenameOne_Template
codename1.ios.debug.provision=C\:\\Users\\[...]\\SocialAppForIOS_development.mobileprovision
codename1.arg.j2me.nativeThemeConst=0
codename1.rim.certificatePassword=
codename1.version=1.0
codename1.ios.certificate=
codename1.icon=icon.png
codename1.rim.signtoolCsk=
codename1.arg.android.debug=false
codename1.rim.signtoolDb=
codename1.arg.ios.includePush=false
codename1.arg.ios.testFlight=false
codename1.packageName=it.sitespa.ios.socialapp
```

---

**UPDATE 3**

I checked with Apple support my device. It's a 32-bit iPad mini ([details here](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP661?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)). I set ios.debug.archs as armv7, but from device logs I can notice the same "**incorrect architecture**" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved installing the .ipa file by means of a third-party software (iTools).

Answer (score 0):

Go over that list again and see if there is something you might have missed. If all else fails connecting the device with a cable and looking at the device logs is what I do in that case.

Comment: I'm talking about native OS logs from before the app launched this will work in xcode if you have a Mac and I understand there are other tools for Windows that will let you inspect that but I'm not familiar with those

Comment: Logs from iPad in the following comments.

Comment: installd[987] <Error>: 0x3c3000 -[MIInstallableBundle performVerificationWithError:]: 487: Incorrect architecture at file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.vRoN6W/extracted/Payload/MyApplication.app/MyApplication

Comment: installd[987] <Error>: 0x3c3000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification stage failed

Comment: itunesstored[916] <Error>: 0x1ca5000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=15 "Incorrect architecture at file:///private/var/mobile/Library

Comment: `Incorrect architecture` means you are trying to install a 32bit app on a 64bit device or a 64bit app on a 32bit device. Can you include the `codenameone_settings.properties` file?

Comment: I added the codenameone_settings.properties file in the question. I also tried setting the ios.debug.archs to arm64 or armv8; in both cases, it returns the same error.

Comment: You should leave the arch blank. It should work for that. I'm low on ideas so I asked Steve if maybe he has some idea. Can you provide some more insight? Which OS version are we talking about, is the device jailbroken?

Comment: Thanks for the support, Shai. OS version: 8.1.1. The device is not jailbroken.

Comment: Just to humour it, try `ios.debug.archs=armv7`  (or when you said you tried `armv8` did you mean `armv7`?)

Comment: I tried setting ios.debug.archs to armv7 and later to armv8. Unfortunately, it returns the same architecture error. What are possible values for ios.debug.archs?

Comment: armv6 armv7 arm64 or any combination separated by spaces should be fine.  You may want to try restarting the device and deleting any existing copies of the app you have installed (if you haven't already) and try again.  If you have a mac, try using lipo to verify what architectures are in there. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47675436/2935174

Comment: My mistake: the iPad has 32-bit architecture (armv7). I modified the question. Anyway, the device returns the same error.

Comment: I installed a third-party software (iTools) on my pc and through it I could successfully install the .ipa file on iPad. Why that behaviour?

Comment: iOS is just funky sometimes. After using itools once you might find out that it works with the QR code again. It's just weird sometimes.